Question regarding proof whether a function is many-one
This question is in regards to the following problem
If
$$
f(x) = \bigl(h_1(x) - h_1(-x)\bigr) \cdot \bigl(h_2(x) - h_2(-x)\bigr) \cdots \bigl(h_{2n+1}(x) - h_{2n+1}(-x)\bigr)
$$
and $f(200) = 0$, the prove that $f(x)$ is a many one function.
The solution to the above problem is given as follows in my textbook
$$
f(-x) = \bigl(h_1(-x) - h_1(x)\bigr) \cdot \bigl(h_2(-x) - h_2(x)\bigr) \cdots \bigl(h_{2n+1}(-x) - h_{2n+1}(x)\bigr)
$$
so
$$
f(-x) = (-1)^{2n+1}f(x) = -f(x)
$$
From here the solution proves that the function is odd and then proves that it is many one.
My question is how did we go from step 1 to step to where did the $(-1)^{2n+1}$ term come from.
Could someone please explain this to me.
Any help would be appreciated!

I would just mention $f(0) = 0 = f(200)$, and done.

In your line of $f(-x)$, each factor $\left(h_i(-x) - h_i(x)\right)$ is equal to $-\left(h_i(x) - h_i(-x)\right)$, and there are $2n+1$ such factors.

@peterwhy Oh thanks! could you post this as an answer so that i can accept it
